# make peer-to-peer voice chat between at least two iOS devices via adHoc network in background

Tags: ios, p2p, gamekit

I want to make an application that enable at least two iOS Devices to have voice chat via adHoc network, which is

iPhone A: adHoc network (WIFI hotspot)
iPhone B: connect to the WIFI hotspot(Iphone A)

then, they can have voice chat to each other when the app is in the background.

Can I do this via Game Kit? If so, can the app be submitted to app store?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot do that in background mode.

Comment: any other way to do it in background? I mean any other libraries.

Comment: in background you cannot run app continuously.